# OpenCV says module object has no attribute face

Tags: python, opencv

I am building a robot with face detection and recognition function.  I have got the face detection part working.  However for face recognition I am getting the following error (using python):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "02_face_training.py", line 21, in <module>
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

I was on opencv 3.2 so I upgraded to opencv 3.4.6 but get the same error.

So I started digging in the source code, and sure enough I don't see any cpp code that defines the Face class, so  I am not sure what's going on.  I even downloaded 4.1 (did not install) just to go through its source and even that did not have any implementation related to face recognition (or at least I could not find it).

This is the code that is causing the issue:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
```

Is there some separate module that I need to install for face recognition in opencv?

I am using python 2.7.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? if you built it fromsource, did you include the `contrib` modules as described here: [How to build OpenCV with extra modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib#how-to-build-opencv-with-extra-modules)

Comment: Yes I was building from the source.  Thanks. This did it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by steeldriver, I needed to download opencv contrib modules and compile them with opencv to get the face recognition features.